# SQL query for last rented car with sunroof feature in car rental system

Tags: sql-server

I'm developing a car rental automation system in SQL, and I'm seeing unwanted data in my table that I've received and constantly updated. The query I need to write is as follows: 'Write a query that retrieves information about the last rented car for customers who have rented cars with the feature of a sunroof at least once.' I've been struggling with it for hours and couldn't solve it. Can you help me?

```
select * from car a
where exists(
    select * from car a2
    inner join customer m on m.customer_id=a2.customer_id
    inner join rent k on k.customer_id=m.customer_id
    inner join car_rent ak on ak.rent_id=k.rent_id
    inner join package_package_option pk on pk.package_id=a2.package_id
    where pk.option_id=2 and a.rent_sell=1
    group by ak.date
    having ak.date = max(ak.date)
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely

Comment: your design is a bit weird, why is car connected to customer? a car only exists by itself, there should be some sort of car_rent table that connects customers with cars

Comment: If I restate the request as: "for each customer who has ever rented a car with a sunroof, select the last rented car for that customer (even if the last car didn't have a sunroof", is that correct? Or do you want the last-rented car having a sunroof for each customer? Your original code grouped by date. Is date significant other than selecting which is last?

Comment: Hello, when you mentioned it, I realized that I have been writing my code incorrectly from the beginning. I hadn't thought about it the way you explained, and you're right. Now, upon reviewing it again, I understand it more clearly. What is required of us is to show the last rented car of a person who has rented any car with a sunroof. It is not necessary for the latest car they rented to have a sunroof. The important thing is to display the last car they rented in the table. @TN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has two steps:

1. Identify all customers who have ever rented a car with a sunroof, and
2. For each such customer, look up the latest rental for each such customer.

The first step is pretty straight forward - Filter the rentals for sunroof and select distinct customer IDs.

The second step can be done a couple of ways. One is to feed the customer IDs into a `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY RentalDate DESC)` construct to select the latest rental for each selected customer one at a time. Another is to lookup all rentals for the selected customers, assign sequence numbers using the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function `OVER(... ORDER BY RentalDate DESC)`, and then filtering for row-number = 1.

Something like (pseudocode):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
    FROM rentals
    WHERE has-a-sunroof
    AND is-a-rental
) C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 rental-info
    FROM rentals R
    WHERE R.customer_id = C.customer_id
    AND is-a-rental
    ORDER BY R.Rentaldate DESC
) R
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT rental-info,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY R.customer_id ORDER BY R.Rentaldate DESC) RowNum
    FROM rentals R
    WHERE R.customer_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
        FROM rentals
        WHERE has-a-sunroof
        AND is-a-rental
    )
    AND is-a-rental
) A
WHERE A.RowNum = 1
```

You might try both to compare performance with large data sets.  I recommend also ensuring that you have an index on the rental that includes both customer_id and rental date for best performance.